# How can I change from TEMPLATE_DIRS to TEMPLATE in Django 1.10

Tags: django, raspberry-pi

How can I change from TEMPLATE_DIRS to TEMPLATE in Django 1.10?

I have tested the raspberry pi automation from the example with TEMPLATE_DIRS as following:

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'templates').replace('\','/'),
)

But now I use Django 1.10 and there is a warning to change from TEMPLATE_DIRS to TEMPLATES

How can I change this code to make it works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the [Upgrading to Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings) section of the manual

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': ...
        'DIRS': [
              os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file),'templates').replace('\','/'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {...},
    },
]
```